# What kind of model do I use to calculate the probability of an observation falling into each of several categories?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, modeling

First off, I don't have a heavy data science background, so if I have the completely wrong approach for this, a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

I am trying to build a series of models to predict how much debt will be acquired by a number of customer insurance policies who cancel.

My first model is a logistic model which predicts the probability of a given policy cancelling at all.

I then want to build a model that predicts, for those who cancel, the probability of them cancelling in month 1, month 2, 3, etc. up to month 12. The sum of these probabilities need to add up to 1. Ideally I'd be able to go so far as day, but I think this would be too complex.

I then have a further logistic model predicting the probability that the customer will have debt on their cancelled policy, and then a linear regression model predicting how much debt.

The probabilities will be multiplied together with the predicted debt to get the expected debt for each customer and then summed over all the customers to get total expected debt. (If I want to predict August debt, I'd only take the predictions from the August model for example)

The challenge is really in predicting when they will cancel and how to fit that into the process correctly. How far into their policy they are when they cancel has a huge impact on both their probability of having debt and value of debt, but it's obviously an unknown for new policies.

Can anyone advise what the best approach is for this? I had originally intended a linear model for predicting when they will cancel, but that's just going to give me an average figure (4 months say) but not anything about how likely they are to fall into the other months, which I really need to work out the expected debt for each month.

Comment: Although the Heckman two-stage model is not time-varying as your case, you still may learn something useful from it.  It uses a binary logistic model and an ols model and multiplies the two to get expected cost.